# Last line of input not included in the loop

Tags: java

I've got the problem that last line from input is avoided on the loop.

Example input:

```
+ 2 3
* 23 23 
/ 65 54
+ 23 23
```

Program is giving me:

```
5
529
1
```

Why last line is not calculated?

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
for(int i = 0; input.hasNextLine(); i++){
        char c = input.next().charAt(0);
        int x = input.nextInt();
        int y = input.nextInt();

        if( c == '*'){
            System.out.println(x*y);
        }
        else if(c == '/'){
            System.out.println(x/y);
        }
        else if(c == '-'){
            System.out.println(x-y);
        }
        else if(c == '+'){
            System.out.println(x+y);
    }
        else if(c == '%'){
            System.out.println(x%y);
        }   
}
```

I've tested also while loop and it is exactly the same. Could you please help?

Comment: Because there is no next line after the last one! Try entering an empty line after last input ;)

Comment: This is working in my eclipse without any correction. Run it again please.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Scanner. 
The command nextInt() doesn't read the enter, so it takes the enter hit as the input for the next Scanner . 
Try to add "String trash= reader.nextLine();" after every nextInt. 
At least that helped me with my Scanner problems :)

Answer (score 0):

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("data")));
String line = "";
while((line=br.readLine())!=-1){
   String[] data = line.split(" ");
   if(data[0].compareTo("+")==0)
     System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(data[1])+Integer.parseInt(data[2]));
   if(data[0].compareTo("*")==0)
     System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(data[1])*Integer.parseInt(data[2]));
   ...
}
```